# View getting re sized on softkeypad open

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am creating a layout with a **scroll view** and a **relative layout**. The problem which I am facing is that the layout is getting re sized as soon as the softkeypad opens.

Here is **layout file**:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="10px" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Training Schedule:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Days:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/days_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/days_textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/days_textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/days_textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/days_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="Time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/time_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/days_editText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timezone_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time_textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Time Zone:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/timezone_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/timezone_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timezone_textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >


    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frequency_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timezone_textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timezone_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="Frequency:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/frequency_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/frequency_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frequency_textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timezone_editText"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notifications_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency_textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frequency_editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Notifications:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notifications_editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/notifications_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notifications_textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency_editText"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the output after running in the emulator:

[image: Emulator Output]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need more changes on your xml file. Please replace the following code frome your existing code, I have done some minor changes.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="10px" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/settings_textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="Training Schedule:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/days_textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingSchedule_textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:text="Days:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/days_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/days_textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/days_textView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trainingSchedule_editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/days_textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/days_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:text="Time:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/time_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/time_textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/time_textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/days_editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="time" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timezone_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time_textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/time_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:text="Time Zone:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/timezone_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/timezone_textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timezone_textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time_editText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/frequency_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timezone_textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timezone_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:text="Frequency:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frequency_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/frequency_textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frequency_textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timezone_editText"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notifications_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency_textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frequency_editText"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:text="Notifications:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/notifications_editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/notifications_textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/notifications_textView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frequency_editText"
            android:ems="10" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_below="xxxx"` this property to Each of your `TextView`.

You have set it in Time only

also add in Timezone,frequency,etc....

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` properties in you manifest file for the activity. Lets say if your activity name is `KeyBoardScrollIssue`. then the activity entry should be as following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".KeyBoardScrollIssue"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_key_board_scroll_issue" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```